# Use "and" and "or" with numbers

Tags: conjunctions

Since the same group of people cannot be in two groups at the same time so I need to use "or". Is this correct?

> No more than **5%** of people fell into the "every day" **or** "never"
> category in any year.

If I use "and", I need to add up the percentages in the two categories. Is this correct?

> Less than **10%** of people fell into the "every day" **and** "never"
> categories in any year.

I have trouble expressing myself this time. I hope you understand my questions.

[image]

Comment: English is not mathematics, or logic. Words like "and" and "or" are often used more loosely than a mathematcian or logician might like - in particular, _or_ can mean inclusive or exclusive "or"  depending on context. (Not an answer to your question, which I haven't read carefully enough to answer: but you might be looking for a precision which doesn't exist).

Comment: Can you pose this question in your language? This is not really an English question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking as a mathematician, I agree with Colin's comment. Neither of your statements means what you think they do. The first one could be interpreted as *"*The **sum** of people in the "every day" and "never" categories is less than 5% of the total*. The best I can do is

> In any year both the "every day" and "never" categories each contained less than 5% of the people.

In the second statement "and" is interpreted inclusive so it says *"Less than 10% of people fell into **both** "every day" and "never" categories in any year.* Which is obvious, as they can't be in one and the other at the same time, so there are 0% in that group.
You have to be very careful and precise if you want to write mathemetics in plain language without ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I understand why my second version doesn't make sense. But I don't understand your explanation of my first version. I think my first version works. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Learner110 I've highlighted the critical word in the first part of my answer. Does that make it any clearer? Your version is not rigerous enough. It doesn't make clear if you are talking about each of the 2 categories taken individually or if they are summed together.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it clear now. But, in everyday life, average people wouldn't go to the trouble to think that two things are summed together when "or" is used, would they?

Comment: @Learner110 Agreed, they wouldn't, but that's exactly what it does mean in logic and electronic circuitry. Unless specified otherwise it is taken as the *inclusive or* rather than *exclusive or* ( either A or B, but not both) as mentioned in Colin's comment.

Comment: Thanks again. Since the *exclusive or* means **either** A or B but not both, will the ambiguity go way if I use "either"? In any year no more than 5% of people fell into **either** the "every day" or the "never" category.

Comment: @Learner110 In my opinion, no. There is still ambiguity. Do you mean the two categories taken together or individually? It is not 100% clear.

Comment: Why? The dictionary says "either" is exclusive. If I use "either", I think the two categories have to be taken individually.